# Find a basis B of R^2 such that the B-matrix of the linear transformation T(x)={{1,2},{3,4}}*x is B={{5,0},{0,-1}}.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This seemed like a really simple problem: We are given a transformation matrix in the standard basis 
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4} 
$$
and the transformation matrix in some other basis 
$$
B=\pmatrix{5&0\\0&-1}
$$ 
So we just need to find some change of coordinate matrix S, such that AS=SB.

I just tried letting S={{a,b},{c,d}}, and ended up with a system of four equations with four unknowns, but when I tried to solve it with RREF, I just got the identity matrix set equal to zero.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your $T(x)$ is not clear!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of looking at the problem:

We want a basis $v_1,v_2$ such that, taking $S$ to be the matrix with columns $v_1,v_2$ (so, taking $S$ to be the change of basis from $B$ to the standard basis), we have
$$
AS = SB
$$
Noting that
$$
AS = A \pmatrix{v_1 & v_2} = \pmatrix{A v_1 & A v_2}\\
SB = \pmatrix{v_1&v_2} \pmatrix{5&0\\0&-1} = \pmatrix{5v_1 & -v_2}
$$
Now, setting the columns of the two matrices equal, we can think of $v_1,v_2$ as follows:  $v_1$ is a solution to the equation
$$
A v_1 = 5 v_1
$$
and $v_2$ is a solution to the equation
$$
A v_2 = -v_2
$$
Try to solve these separately.